# how to make MS Word Macro to add a new blank page without any headers or footers from last page

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to make a macro for word.
I have many word docs with 2 pages or more and they have same headers, footers
I am trying to make a macro which will add an additional blank page to the doc but should not carry any header/footer and should not affect the previous pages. So a new blank page with basically nothing.

```
    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
    Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
    Selection.InsertNewPage

    Selection.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).LinkToPrevious = False
    Selection.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Delete
    Selection.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).LinkToPrevious = False
    Selection.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Delete
```

So far this macro gives me an additional page with header/footer followed by a blank page.
Any thoughts/ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in the question is on the right track with using the `Section` object, `LinkToPrevious` and `Range.Delete`. What's generating the additional page is

```
Selection.InsertNewPage
```

The line `Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage` already creates a new page.

FWIW, the code I'd use would be the same in principle, but would work with `Range` instead of the `Selection` object. Working with a `Range` is generally faster and there's minimal screen flicker. It also tends to be more accurate, and it's easier to determine what the code is affecting. I'm providing it for information purposes :-)

```
Sub NewPageSectionNoHF()
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim rng As Word.Range
    Dim sec As Word.Section
    Dim hf As Word.HeaderFooter

    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    Set rng = doc.content
    rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    rng.InsertBreak Word.WdBreakType.wdSectionBreakNextPage
    Set sec = rng.Sections(1)

    'First page
    Set hf = sec.Headers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage)
    If hf.exists Then
        hf.LinkToPrevious = False
        hf.Range.Delete
    End If
    Set hf = sec.Footers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage)
    If hf.exists Then
        hf.LinkToPrevious = False
        hf.Range.Delete
    End If

    'Other pages
    Set hf = sec.Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary)
    hf.LinkToPrevious = False
    hf.Range.Delete
    Set hf = sec.Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary)
    hf.LinkToPrevious = False
    hf.Range.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried with adding command to set different first page header/footer option and after that its working ok in my scenario. It may be different for others.